# Minimize $\| Ax-b \|$

Tags: optimization

$A$ is a $n \times m$ matrix with known real elements and $b$ is a known real $n$-dimensional vector.

I would like to find all $x$ such that $\| Ax-b \|$ is a minimum.

Is there a theorem that deals with it?

***Update:***
What changes if we add the constraint that all $x$'s coordinates must be positive reals?

Comment: This is called "least-squares approximation/regression/solution". Googling any of those terms will give you lots of info.

Comment: meanwhile, standardized methodology used in the setting of Kalman filters, so, books on that...

Comment: What do you mean by $bI$? Is it a matrix or a vector? Also is $x$ a matrix or a vector (according to how you define $bI$).

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I have updated the question as I need solutions for x coordinates positive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to minimize
$$
|Ax-b|^2 = (Ax-b)^t (Ax-b) = x^t A^t A x - 2 x^t A^t b + |b|^2 
$$
derive to obtain
$$
2 A^t A x - 2A^t b = 0
$$
which gives
$$
x = (A^t A)^{-1} A^t b.
$$

Comment: For those curious, when he writes $b^2$, he just means $b^t b$, which, if you wanted, can be simplified to $|b|^2$

Comment: corrected, thanks!

Comment: I am wondering can you give more explanation why gives vector gives the desired minimum and did you find it?

Answer (score 2):

The vector x is given by $$x=(A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T}b$$ As suggested by commentators, read up on least-squares approximations.

Comment: Also note that the kernel of A must be zero-dimensional for the matrix $A^{T}A$ to be invertible.